# How do I get a good directory difffile I can use to patch/what to use for patch

Tags: windows, gui, diff, patch

I'd like to make a clean diff of a directory that allows me
to later use a gui patch program for windows to apply the diffile.

If possible I don't want to have to deal with hardcoded paths in the diffile.

Also what program can I use for gui patching?

Answer (score 0):

Our [compare and merge tool ECMerge](http://www.elliecomputing.com) does that. It can produce patches (open a folder diff and export a patch) then apply them, the GUI patch application let you review the effect of the patch in a temporary folder (and you just have to press the Write results button to actually finalize the application).